# CTE SQL query get full paths

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy, common-table-expression

I have got simple query

```
WITH  conn_cte ( ParentCategoryId, CategoryId, IdsPath )
        AS ( SELECT ParentCategoryId
                   ,CategoryId
                   ,CAST(ParentCategoryId AS varchar(1000))
             FROM   Ind_CategoriesConnections
             WHERE  ParentCategoryId = 0
             UNION ALL
             SELECT cc.ParentCategoryId
                   ,cc.CategoryId
                   ,CAST(IdsPath + ','
                    + CAST (cc.ParentCategoryId AS varchar(5)) AS varchar(1000))
             FROM   Ind_CategoriesConnections AS cc
                    INNER JOIN conn_cte AS conn ON conn.CategoryId = cc.ParentCategoryId
                                                   AND cc.categoryid NOT IN (
                                                   SELECT conn.Categoryid )
           )
  SELECT  x.*
  FROM    ( SELECT  t.ParentCategoryId
                   ,t.CategoryId
                   ,t.IdsPath + ',' + CAST(t.CategoryId AS varchar(5)) AS [path]
            FROM    conn_cte t
                    INNER JOIN Ind_Categories c ON t.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
                                                   AND c.CategoryViewId = 1
                                                   AND c.IsActiveYN = 1
          ) x
  ORDER BY x.path
```

I am interesting in query (optimal) that only return full paths from root to leaf.

for example the part of result is

```
Parent  Child   Path
12       16     0,8,12,16
16       17     0,8,12,16,17
17       18     0,8,12,16,17,18
17       19     0,8,12,16,17,19
```

zero is root 18,19 are leafs (and children), I want to ignore partly paths like `0,8,12,16` and `0,8,12,16,17` and get only full paths (ended with leafs) 
`0,8,12,16,17,18` and `0,8,12,16,17,19`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say something like:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM conn_cte AS parents WHERE t.path LIKE parents.path + '%')
```

Comment: But bear in mind that if you have 0,8,12,16,17,183 - that could stuff you around. You may want to put the comma on earlier, so that your path actually looks like `0,8,12,16,17,18,`

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
  ( 
   Id int
  ,ParentId int
  )

INSERT  INTO @tbl
        ( Id, ParentId )
VALUES  ( 0, NULL )
,       ( 8, 0 )
,       ( 12, 8 )
,       ( 16, 12 )
,       ( 17, 16 )
,       ( 18, 17 )
,       ( 19, 17 )

;
WITH  abcd
        AS (
              -- anchor
            SELECT   id
                    ,ParentID
                    ,CAST(id AS VARCHAR(100)) AS [Path]
            FROM    @tbl
            WHERE   ParentId IS NULL
            UNION ALL
              --recursive member
            SELECT  t.id
                   ,t.ParentID
                   ,CAST(a.[Path] + ',' + CAST( t.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS [Path]
            FROM    @tbl AS t
                    JOIN abcd AS a ON t.ParentId = a.id
           )
SELECT  Id ,ParentID ,[Path]
FROM    abcd
WHERE   Id NOT IN ( SELECT  ParentId
                    FROM    @tbl
                    WHERE   ParentId IS NOT NULL )
```

Returns

```
Id          ParentID    Path
----------- ----------- ----------------------
18          17          0,8,12,16,17,18
19          17          0,8,12,16,17,19
```

The syntax is SQL Server 2008, for 2005 change the `INSERT INTO @tbl ...` syntax.